# multiprocessing timestamp takes a lot of time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I created a program that spawn processes and run the provided algorithm. When I run the algorithm without multiprocessing it takes 1.7 sec, but when I spawn two processes that run the same algorithm it takes 18 sec.

Profiler result for one process without spawning:
`68050    0.084    0.000    0.084    0.000 {method 'timestamp' of 'datetime.datetime' objects}`

With spawning two processes for one of spawned processes:
`34025   15.947    0.000   15.947    0.000 {method 'timestamp' of 'datetime.datetime' objects}`

Why the date.timestamp takes 15.9 sec? Is this profiler error ?

Spawn:

```
# Start processes
for index, simulation in enumerate(self.simulations):
    proc = Process(target=simulation_runner, args=(simulation, queues[index]))
    jobs.append(proc)
    proc.start()
```

Timestamp:

```
timestamp = math.floor(date.timestamp())
```

Also I wrote the program that do the same:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from datetime import datetime


def worker(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r+') as file:
        for line in file:
            date = datetime.now()
            date.timestamp()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    args = ['FLT-TEST', 'FLT-TEST']
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(worker, args)
    # worker('FLT-TEST')
    print(f'Executing in {time.time() - start} s.')
```

Without spawning it prints `Executing in 0.16368794441223145 s.`
With spawning it prints `Executing in 66.31291604042053 s.`
`FLT-TEST` contains 91849 lines

Without file reading

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from datetime import datetime


def worker(num):
    print(f'Process {num}')
    for _ in range(95000):
        date = datetime.now()
        date.timestamp()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    args = [1, 2]
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(worker, args)
    # worker(1)
    print(f'Executing in {time.time() - start} s.')
```

I get the same results.

Comment: It's probably due to the processing involved of having the OS create and launch a separate task. `multiprocessing` can involve a lot of overhead.

Comment: Comment: You should consider using a [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) for timing stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
timestamp = math.floor(date.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())
```

Setting timezone fixed time duration.